# HTML, CSS, JQUERY not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use jQuery to animate a menu, making it enter the page from off screen when clicked. When I click on the menu button, the button just highlights. It's not working, what am I missing? Here's the code:

HTML

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Mrs. Rogers Math</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="mrm2.css"/>

<!--LINK TO JQUERY & FILE-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
    <a href="http://www.mrsrogersmath.net"><img id="logoImg" src="http://www.mrsrogersmath.net/SVG_logo_2.png" alt="logoImg"></a>
    <img class="menuButton" src="http://www.mrsrogersmath.net/menuButton.png" alt="menuButton">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li id="menuLinks">Home </li>
        <li id="menuLinks">Math Fun </li>
        <li id="menuLinks">Helpful Links </li>
        <li id="menuLinks">Contact Me </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>document.write(jQuery.now());</script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
#header{
position: relative;
background-color:#636363;
width: auto;
height: 106px;
z-index: -1;
}

#logoImg{
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 1;
}

.menuButton{
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
top: 20px;
z-index: 1;
background-color: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.menu{
position: absolute;
right:-300px;
top:-18px;
z-index: 1;
width: 250px;
height: 400px;
background-color: #636363;
list-style-type: none;
border-radius:25px;
}

#menuLinks{
/*display:inline;*/
font-size: 15px;
color: white;
font-size:35px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-top: 20px;
background-color:none;
}
```

JQUERY

```
var main = function() {

  $('.menuButton').click(function() {
$('.menu').animate({
  right: "10px"
}, 200);

  });
};


$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's about your `#header` having a negative `z-index`. It's "hidden" behind the body which results in you not being able to actually click the `.menuButton`.

*Longer explaination:* Giving the menu button a higher `z-index` than one of its parent elements (in this case, the `#header`) doesn't have any effect - it will still compete successfully with other descendants of the `#header` but it will not be displayed on top of *the `#headers` parents or siblings*. The `#header`'s `z-index` will be the "dominant" one.

*See also:* [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) as referred by @ajp15243 in the comments.

Comment: This is correct. The `#header` element could be given a `z-index` of `0` instead: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x9d0krkm/)

Comment: The [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) is basically what you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var main = function() {

  $('.menuButton').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({
        right: "10px"}, 200);

    });
  };


$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
#header{
position: relative;
background-color:#636363;
width: auto;
height: 106px;
z-index: 0;
}

#logoImg{
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 1;
}

.menuButton{
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
top: 20px;
z-index: 5;
background-color: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.menu{
position: absolute;
right:-300px;
top:-18px;
z-index: 1;
width: 250px;
height: 400px;
background-color: #636363;
list-style-type: none;
border-radius:25px;
}

#menuLinks{
/*display:inline;*/
font-size: 15px;
color: white;
font-size:35px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-top: 20px;
background-color:none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>Mrs. Rogers Math</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="mrm2.css"/>

<!--LINK TO JQUERY & FILE-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
    <a href="http://www.mrsrogersmath.net"><img id="logoImg" src="http://www.mrsrogersmath.net/SVG_logo_2.png" alt="logoImg"></a>
    <img class="menuButton" src="http://www.mrsrogersmath.net/menuButton.png" alt="menuButton">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li id="menuLinks">Home </li>
        <li id="menuLinks">Math Fun </li>
        <li id="menuLinks">Helpful Links </li>
        <li id="menuLinks">Contact Me </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>document.write(jQuery.now());</script>

</body>

</html>
```

here, fixed for you.